# Creating delay in DOS Batch with ERRORLEVEL 0

Tags: windows, batch-file

I had previously found this method for simulating a batch file running (inserting the line into a .bat file):
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000 >NUL

It works and produces a 2 second delay but is causing me issues because it is returning errorlevel = 1 
[image]

Why does it not return errorlevel = 0 ?

Comment: The IP `1.1.1.1` is now taken by CloudFlare, so this will not wait for 2s but return in some ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply timeout:

```
C:\>timeout 2

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Edit: Well at least for Windows 7 and higher

Answer (score 2):

You're simulating a delay with a failed ping.  Therefore, `ping` is returning errorlevel 1 because the ping itself failed.  If you execute a successful ping, `ping 127.0.0` for example, errorlevel will be 0.

As Vinzenz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910125/277307) states, on any modern Windows system (Vista+), favor the [`timeout`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754891.aspx) command instead.  It will provide you with reliable errorlevels for checking a delay.

```
C:\>timeout 2 2>&1 1>nul

C:\>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0

C:\>timeout 2 2>&1 1>nul

(<ENTER> pressed before timeout)

C:\>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0

C:\>timeout 2 2>&1 1>nul

^C (<CONTROL>+C pressed before timeout)

C:\>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
-1073741510

C:\>timeout /nobreak 2 2>&1 1>nul

(<CONTROL>+C pressed before timeout)

C:\>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users>ping -n 3 localhost >nul

C:\Users>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Comment: This was flagged as a low quality post, which seems unusual from a high rep member. Regardless, explain how your code works!

Answer (score 1):

Use ping to localhost. It is possible a remote host is not reachable. This will cause the error.